# How to get redirected url after oauth call

Tags: spotify, gnome-shell-extensions

I am learning to use APIs, so I am making a Gnome Shell Extension consisting of buttons in the top bar in Ubuntu to control Spotify's player (next, play, pause, previous) by doing calls to Spotify's API. Until now, I was getting my token manually, but as they expire after 1h, I would like to add some code to do it in the background on a click.

When doing it manually, I go to `accounts.spotify.com/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost` (with a lot of stuff behind), I am then redirected to the specified url with a code in it (localhost for testing, but I have a domain name if needed). I am wondering how can I get this code from the url back in my program ?

(Note : my program is written in JS, but not run in a web browser nor NodeJS. Therefor, I had to use LibSoup to make my GET and POST requests. I guess I can do my request to `accounts.spotify.com/authorize` with a GET and not specify any header ?)

Thank you for your help

Comment: When you execute a GET request, the access token should be inside of the response. If successful, you then have to parse the access token from the response.

Answer (score 0):

If your token expires within an hour it appears you are using the implicit grant authorization flow. Perhaps you should use the authorization code flow ([documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/)) so that you have refreshable tokens.